# store values values uses the default values first and then uses the data from the localstorage

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am having an issue with my SvelteKit application. In my store.ts file, I have a defaultValues object that contains values to be used when there is no data in localstorage. The problem is that when the application is loaded, the default values are initially displayed, even if there is data in localstorage. After a flicker, the data from localstorage is then used, which gives an sickly experience when reloading the page.

```js
//store.ts

import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store'; // import the writable and derived store from svelte
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
type ID = string | null; 
const defaultValues: Record<string, Book[] | ID> = { // this object contains the default values to be used if there are no data in localstorage
    books: [
        // the books array , which is array of book objects
        // the book interface is in the global.d.ts file
        {
            id: "4", // i have used the crypto.randomuuid to generate the unique id
            title: `Typescript`,
            notes: [{ id: crypto.randomUUID(), title: `Example note`, content: `# Hello world` }]
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            title: `Python`,
            notes: [{ id: crypto.randomUUID(), title: `Example note`, content: `# Hello world` }]
        }
    ],
    currentBookId: null,
    currentNoteId: null
};

function getValue<T>(key: string): T {
    if (browser && localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) as string) as T;
    } else {
        return defaultValues[key] as T;
    }
}

export const books = writable<Book[]>(getValue<Book[]>('books'));
books.subscribe((value) => {
    if (browser) {
        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(value));
    }
});
export const currentBookId = writable<ID>(getValue<ID>('currentBookId'));
currentBookId.subscribe((value) => {
    if (browser) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentBookId', JSON.stringify(value));
    }
});

export const currentNoteId = writable<ID>(getValue<ID>('currentNoteId'));
currentNoteId.subscribe((value) => {
    if (browser) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentNoteId', JSON.stringify(value));
    }
});
```

For example, if I rename the title of a book in the defaultValues.books object and reload the page, I would expect the updated title to be displayed immediately. However, what happens is that the old title is initially rendered and then it changes to the updated title. I don't want this behavior.
BTW, this store even works only on production and  not in development. Any help regarding this also will be  greatly appreciated.
Thank you in

Answer (score 0):

That is not really something you can avoid if you are using server-side rendering (the default) and the data only exists on the client.

Either [disable SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr), which can have negative performance implications, or store the data on the server and pass it to the page e.g. via the [`load` functions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load).

One third option would probably be to hide just the piece of markup that displays data from the store until the data is loaded. Though this will probably cause layout shifts which generally should be avoided.

Comment: would I face the same problem, if I use indexdb instead of local storage?

Comment: Yes, that is also entirely on the client.